# jQuery.ajax().abort() _ browser still receives the data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In jQuery, if I abort an ajax call, is it loaded by the browser in full, and then dumped from memory and not event-handled? Or are just the headers loaded? In a more complex script I'm noticing that sometimes all the data is received before marked as aborted in Firefox/Firebug.

javascript:

```
var $ajax;
function fetch(){
if ($ajax && $ajax.statusCode != 200) $ajax.abort();
$ajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    data:{search:"term"},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'http://localhost/data.php',
    success: function(_data){ },
});
}

fetch();
fetch();
```

data.php:

```
print 'naptime!';
sleep(2);
```

Comment: Possibly related to the fact that you are using localhost so transfers are going to very quick. And the fact that you are not loading much data. Also, by the time you have received the response code in your localhost environment the request would already be complete. You need to test this with more data and in a more production like environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved in comments! Thanks ZeSimon

> Possibly related to the fact that you are using localhost so transfers are going to very quick. And the fact that you are not loading much data. Also, by the time you have received the response code in your localhost environment the request would already be complete. You need to test this with more data and in a more production like environment. – ZeSimon